# "ip rule show" does not take any arguments

Tags: iproute

I'm trying to get the routing rules for a specific IP but the `ip rule` command throws an error.  Shouldn't this work like the `add`/`del` etc. ? At least that seems to me from the docs.

```
$ ip rule list 192.168.1.100
"ip rule show" does not take any arguments.
```

Doc:

```
$ ip rule help
Usage: ip rule [ list | add | del | flush ] SELECTOR ACTION
SELECTOR := [ not ] [ from PREFIX ] [ to PREFIX ] [ tos TOS ] [ fwmark FWMARK[/MASK] ]
            [ iif STRING ] [ oif STRING ] [ pref NUMBER ]
ACTION := [ table TABLE_ID ]
          [ prohibit | reject | unreachable ]
          [ realms [SRCREALM/]DSTREALM ]
          [ goto NUMBER ]
          SUPPRESSOR
SUPPRESSOR := [ suppress_prefixlength NUMBER ]
              [ suppress_ifgroup DEVGROUP ]
TABLE_ID := [ local | main | default | NUMBER ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it takes no arguments.  Explicitly documented in [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html).

> #### ip rule show - list rules
>
> This command has no arguments.  The options `list` or `lst` are synonyms with `show`.

Comment: I might have misread the doc but isn't ``ip rule [ list | add | del | flush ] SELECTOR ACTION`` means that `list` , `add`, `del` and `flush` takes a `SELECTOR` and `ACTION` ? How does this syntax say that `list` takes no argument but `add` does?

Comment: @AnthonyHunt Agreed.  How about sending a patch to correct this help to [the upstream](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2)?